# Can't find .so in the same directory as the executable?

Tags: linux, autoloader

I have an executable which needs to link with `libtest.so` dynamically,so I put them in the same directory,then :

```
cd path_to_dir
./binary
```

But got this:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libtest.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How can it be unable to find `libtest.so` which is already in the same directory as the executable itself?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The loader never checks the current directory for shared objects unless it is explicitly directed to via `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. See the `ld.so(8)` man page for more details.

Comment: `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is empty on my machine:(

Comment: So ld can work well without `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`,what's it for then?

Comment: It specifies additional directories for the loader to look in for libraries.

Comment: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH};.`,I'm getting a syntax error,what's wrong here...?I'm doing it this way elsewhere,which never reports error...

Comment: Paths in *nix are separated by a colon (`:`), not a semicolon.

Comment: LD_LIBRARY_PATH is generally a poor choice in production. It is good for quick hacks, and things like helping uninstalled binaries find their shared libraries when running unit tests (think ./configure; make; make check). When building your binary, you can either put your library in a standard location (listed at /etc/ld.so.conf) or pass the -R flag to the linker to let the binary know where to look.

Answer (score 79):

While you can set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to let the dynamic linker know where to look, there are better options. You can put your shared library in one of the standard places, see `/etc/ld.so.conf` (on Linux) and `/usr/bin/crle` (on Solaris) for the list of these places

You can pass `-R <path>` to the linker when building your binary, which will add `<path>` to the list of directories scanned for your shared library. Here's an example. First, showing the problem:

libtest.h:

```c
void hello_world(void);
```

libtest.c:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
void hello_world(void) {
  printf("Hello world, I'm a library!\n");
}
```

hello.c:

```c
#include "libtest.h"
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  hello_world();
}
```

Makefile (tabs must be used):

```makefile
all: hello
hello: libtest.so.0
%.o: %.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -fPIC -c -o $@ $<
libtest.so.0.0.1: libtest.o
        $(CC) -shared -Wl,-soname,libtest.so.0 -o libtest.so.0.0.1 libtest.o
libtest.so.0: libtest.so.0.0.1
        ln -s $< $@
clean:
        rm -f hello libtest.o hello.o libtest.so.0.0.1 libtest.so.0
```

Let's run it:

```
$ make
cc  -fPIC -c -o libtest.o libtest.c
cc -shared -Wl,-soname,libtest.so.0 -o libtest.so.0.0.1 libtest.o
ln -s libtest.so.0.0.1 libtest.so.0
cc     hello.c libtest.so.0   -o hello
$ ./hello 
./hello: error while loading shared libraries: libtest.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How to fix it? Add `-R <path>` to the linker flags (here, by setting `LDFLAGS`).

```
$ make clean
(...)
$ make LDFLAGS="-Wl,-R -Wl,/home/maciej/src/tmp"
(...)
cc   -Wl,-R -Wl,/home/maciej/src/tmp  hello.c libtest.so.0   -o hello
$ ./hello 
Hello world, I'm a library!
```

Looking at the binary, you can see that it needs `libtest.so.0`:

```
$ objdump -p hello | grep NEEDED
  NEEDED               libtest.so.0
  NEEDED               libc.so.6
```

The binary will look for its libraries, apart from the standard places, in the specified directory:

```
$ objdump -p hello | grep RPATH
  RPATH                /home/maciej/src/tmp
```

If you want the binary to look in the current directory, you can set the RPATH to `$ORIGIN`. This is a bit tricky, because you need to make sure that the dollar sign is not interpreted by make. Here's one way to do it:

```
$ make CFLAGS="-fPIC" LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath '-Wl,\$\$ORIGIN'"
$ objdump -p hello | grep RPATH
  RPATH                $ORIGIN
$ ./hello 
Hello world, I'm a library!
```

Comment: If not using `make`, such as when manually calling `g++`, try `-Wl,-rpath='$ORIGIN'` (note the single quotes) to prevent `$ORIGIN` from expanding to an empty string.

Comment: This info was very useful, thanks. Without it, I was resorting to launching an executable with a wrapping shell script `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./my-executable $@` whereas using the `-rpath='.'` is (still a workaround in my case, but) much cleaner.

Comment: I think I don't get it completly. First you are using `-R` and later `-rpath` to pass the additional search path to the linker. What's the difference?

Comment: The `-R` and `-rpath` options (on the `ld` command) are interchangeable with some caveats, see `man ld` for details.

Comment: This $ORIGIN solution works really well. I used to have `-rpath=.`, but this works only when you start the executable from it's folder (`./my-exe`), from another folder (`./folder/my-exe`) it used to fail. With `-rpath=$ORIGIN`, it works from any place!

Answer (score 35):

To load the shared objects from the same directory as your executable, simply execute:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./binary
```

Note: It will not modify the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable of your system. The change only affects to this, and only this, execution of your program.

Answer (score 15):

For anyone using [CMake](https://cmake.org/) for their build, you can set the `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS` to the following:

```
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -Wl,-rpath='$ORIGIN'")
```

This will properly propagate the linker flags for all build types (e.g., Debug, Release, etc...) to look for .so files in the current working directory first.

Comment: Hey, this is super useful. I can prepare a derivative library B using library A, redistribute library A with my library B, and be immune to library A variations on the user's system. Are there downsides to this approach?

Comment: Oh, and I seem to be able to do this with bazel's cc_library: `linkopts = ["-Wl,-rpath '-Wl,$$ORIGIN'"]`...

Answer (score 5):

For anyone that still struggles without an answer I found one myself with the following suggestion:

You could try updating the ld.so.cache using: `sudo ldconfig -v`

Worked for me.

Comment: Could you explain a little in which way this helps solving the OP's problem?

Comment: It also solved problem for me, but I additionally looked at /etc/ld.so.conf for directories where the library files are searched, and placed my library to the first directory in the list (namely, /usr/local/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/).

Then I executed this command and boom, the library is now found.

Answer (score 2):

I got it working with this :

```
$ gcc file.c -L. -lmylib
```

and to run :

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./a.out
```

Answer (score 2):

There can be subtle situations showing the same symptoms. I use to build a CMake project, both locally at `/path/to/myproj` and remotely on a server, at `/path/to/myproj-deploy`. Project contains an `.so` build artifact and multiple ELF files depending on that.

When I pulled back binaries from the build server, I found out that (locally) calling ELFs results in the same problems.
Thanks to [authomatthias](https://serverfault.com/users/6755), calling

```
$ objdump -p bin/myelf  | grep my
bin/myelf:     file format elf64-x86-64
  NEEDED               libmyso.so
  RUNPATH              /path/to/myproj-deploy/bin
```

ends up in a non-surprising consequence: CMake system hardcoded remote path into the `RUNPATH`, demonstrating some non-portability (without proper additional actions, I suppose)

Answer (score 1):

The dynamic linker will decide where to look for libraries. In case of Linux, the dynamic linker usually is `GNU ld.so` (or an alternative that will usually behave identical for compatibility reasons).

To quotes from the Wikipedia:

> The dynamic linker of the GNU C Library searches for shared libraries
> in the following locations:
>
> 1. The (colon-separated) paths in the `DT_RPATH` dynamic section attribute of the binary if present and the `DT_RUNPATH` attribute does
>    not exist.
> 2. The (colon-separated) paths in the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, unless the executable is a `setuid`/`setgid` binary, in
>    which case it is ignored. `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` can be overridden by calling
>    the dynamic linker with the option --library-path (e.g.
>    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 --library-path $HOME/mylibs myprogram).
> 3. The (colon-separated) paths in the `DT_RUNPATH` dynamic section attribute of the binary if present.
> 4. Lookup based on the *ldconfig cache file* (often located at `/etc/ld.so.cache`) which contains a compiled list of candidate
>    libraries previously found in the augmented library path (set by
>    `/etc/ld.so.conf`). If, however, the binary was linked with the `-z nodefaultlib` linker option, libraries in the default library paths are
>    skipped.
> 5. In the trusted default path `/lib`, and then `/usr/lib`. If the binary was linked with the -z nodefaultlib linker option, this step is
>    skipped.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath

Answer (score 1):

If your dependencies have also dependencies RUNPATH will not work (which is the default tag by recent linkers). To solve the problem you should use RPATH old version by adding `--disable-new-dtags`.

```
-Wl,--disable-new-dtags,-rpath=path/to/libs
```